# Scrolling in TextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` with **Scrolling Enabled**.

My problem is that the TextView is small, width for two lines, adding successive lines the scroll does not appear to move around the TextView. 
In short, I need to know how to implement the "scroll" according to the TextView grows.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are more content in text view with respect to size of text view then by

```
yourTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

will scroll add the scrolling behaviour in your text view.

But if your text view's content is equal or less than to your text view's size then there is no need to scroll the text.

Answer (score 0):

By default the TextView scrolls in vertical direction. So, when your content inside TextView will become more than its frame.height, it will automatically allow you to scroll vertically.